# Replace text in a wordpress file with a hook

Tags: php, wordpress, hook, woocommerce

I am trying to replace some text in a woocommerce file so i need to create a hook in my functions.php file so that when woocommerce updates, it won't harm my site by reverting back to the original code.

I'm trying to replace this part of the code:

```
<h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
```

with this:

```
<div class="caption"><h5><?php the_title(); ?></h5>
  <div class="category-main-points"><?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_short_description', $post->post_excerpt ) ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's the part of code from the original file:

```
<li <?php post_class( $classes ); ?>>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item' ); ?>

<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">

    <?php
        /**
         * woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title hook
         *
         * @hooked woocommerce_show_product_loop_sale_flash - 10
         * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail - 10
         */
        do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title' );
    ?>

    <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>

    <?php
        /**
         * woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title hook
         *
         * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_price - 10
         */
        do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title' );
    ?>

</a>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item' ); ?>

</li>
```

and here's my hook so far:

```
<?php
// Add text to content-product-cat to help with styling
add_action('woocommerce_before_subcategory_title', 'woohook_before_subcategory_title');

function woohook_before_subcategory_title() {
ob_start();

}

add_action('woocommerce_after_subcategory_title', 'woohook_after_subcategory_title');

function woohook_after_subcategory_title() {
 $subcategory_title = ob_get_clean();

}
?>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Woocommerce allows you to override its templates, just copy the original file to `./wp-content/themes/my-theme/woocommerce/` and edit away!

Comment: Hi diggy this seems to have worked on a lot of files but i've just edited the empty-cart.php file and it's not working. The original file location is in woocomerce/templates/cart, i've

Comment: Hi diggy this seems to have worked on a lot of files but i've just edited the empty-cart.php file and it's not working. The original file location is in woocomerce/templates/cart, i've added a new file to my woocommerce folder as mentioned earlier for other files like content-product_cat.php and they work, but empty-cart.php doesn't, any ideas?

Comment: I guess you'd have to respect the folder structure, so try placing it in `./wp-content/themes/my-theme/woocommerce/cart/`

Comment: Thanks diggy, i thought i did that already but i put it in templates/cart instead of just cart